# How to check `return value` or `other values which are not contained in variables` with javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, coding-style, debugging

I use javascript debugger of chrome.
How can I check the following values which are not contained in variables by using the debugger?

`a + b` of

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b
}
```

`a > 0` of `if (a > 0 && b > 0)`

`f() + 2` of `v += f() + 2`

If debugger have no functionality to check them, I have to write codes like followings.
But these way of coding sacrifice both writablitiy and readablity for debuggability.
Should I write codes like the followings?
Is this good and normal way of coding?

```
function add(a, b) {
    var ret = a + b
    return ret
}
```

```
var _a = a > 0
var _b = b > 0
if (_a && _b)
```

```
var t = f() + 2
v += t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the breakpoints feature. Set a breakpoint on "return a + b;" and call add(1, 2) using the console. The breakpoint should pause execution, and you can type "a + b" into the console to see the result.

Comment: thank you very much. your information made my life easier! why do you know this secret function of debugger?